# Can you "augment" a person?

Tags: word-choice

Can you ***augment*** a person? The word means

> to make greater, more numerous, larger, or more intense ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment))

But is it odd to say

> ***Augment*** every employee ... with a technology?

This is for a technology company. I think they want to urge companies (their customers) to empower or equip employees with the technology in question. They’re trying to say “Give your employees new tools so they’re better at their job.”

Comment: What do you want it to mean?

Comment: I think they want it to mean, "Empower" or "Equip" employees with a new technology. It's about giving the employees a new tool that will help them in their jobs.

Comment: @user66974 Note that in most examples _employees_ is in genitive. The actual object of _augment_ is an abstract noun.

Comment: Augment their skills, not themselves.

Comment: This sounds like contamination of HR-speak by semi-illiterate neologisms drawn from what I shall refer to as "gaming". Like most 21st century jargon its principal characteristic is its superfluity. We don't need this to be introduced into HR-speak. But it will be, precisely because it is so unnecessary, i.e. and not witty.

Comment: "Augment" has been used in many sci-fi/fantasy contexts to describe cyborgs, genetically "augmented" people, or those with superpowers. Please edit to tell more about the meaning you're looking for; for these kind of meanings it could be reasonable. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gaming jargon, the term ***augmentation*** is used to mean:

> the process by which players use their Invention skill to enhance weapons, shields, armour, and tools. Items can be augmented with the use of an augmentor, and a gizmo shell can then be added to hold various perks. ([Runescape Wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Augmentation#:%7E:text=Augmentation%20is%20the%20process%20by,added%20to%20hold%20various%20perks.))

So probably the author of this sentence is trying to extend this meaning to other contexts. However, as you can see from the examples provided by most dictionaries, you can only ***augment*** inanimate nouns such as

> report, income ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment))
> knowledge, photographs ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/augment)) etc.

If the context of the sentence is not gaming, I would not recommend the use of ***augment***.

Your suggestion, ***equip***, would be far better.

Comment: But this is HR. They are not happy unless it is annoying, unnecessary, lacking in wit and superfluous.

Comment: I think you can augment a person. There are now power suits which, for example, allow a human to lift weights far in excess of what they could unaided. These are described by some as augmented.